# can we create .exe for ribbon outlook in visual studio?

Tags: c#, outlook, ribbon

I written code for ribbon outlook and I want create setup for this. tried to create setup with visual studio with setup and Deployment option.

Comment: It will be quite helpful to describe the steps you followed.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your solution using the following ways:

- [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019)
- [Deploy an Office solution by using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2019)